# Switch themes in angular material 5

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular5

I been reading a few articles on this but they seem to be conflicting in several different ways. I am hoping to re-create the same theme switching as the [angular material documentation site](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) for the latest version of angular material [5.0.0-rc0]

I have two custom themes, this is custom-theme.scss and there is light-custom-theme.scss which is nearly identical, sans the mat-dark-theme

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
$custom-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$custom-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-orange, A200, A100, A400);
$custom-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$custom-theme: mat-dark-theme($custom-theme-primary, $custom-theme-accent, $custom-theme-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);
```

My styles.scss looks like so

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
@import 'custom-theme.scss';
@import 'light-custom-theme.scss';
.custom-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);
}

.light-custom-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($light-custom-theme);
}
```

And then it's called in the index.html `<body class="mat-app-background">`

Everything works fine when I do one theme. But I am trying to switch between the two. Adding both themes into angular-cli.json, the light-custom-theme takes over

```
"styles": [
  "styles.scss",
  "custom-theme.scss",
  "light-custom-theme.scss"
],
```

I have the following code in place in one of my components to handle toggling themes

```
toggleTheme(): void {
  if (this.overlay.classList.contains("custom-theme")) {
    this.overlay.classList.remove("custom-theme");
    this.overlay.classList.add("light-custom-theme");
  } else if (this.overlay.classList.contains("light-custom-theme")) {
    this.overlay.classList.remove("light-custom-theme");
    this.overlay.classList.add("custom-theme");
  } else {
    this.overlay.classList.add("light-custom-theme");
  }
}
```

But whenever it runs the theme remains the same. For what it is worth, there is already a "cdk-overlay-container" object at position 0 in overlay.classList

```
0:"cdk-overlay-container"
1:"custom-theme"
length:2
value:"cdk-overlay-container custom-theme"
```

I am unsure how to debug this as the angular material documentation doesn't give me too much to work with, any help would be appreciative!

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution for Angular 5.1+/Angular Material 5.0+.

*Edit: As noted, this still works in Angular 7+.

Working editable example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-material-theming

In theme.scss, include a default theme(notice it isn't kept under a class name - this is so Angular will use it as the default), and then a light and dark theme.

**theme.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

// Typography
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: Raleway,
  $headline: mat-typography-level(24px, 48px, 400),
  $body-1: mat-typography-level(16px, 24px, 400)
);
@include angular-material-typography($custom-typography);

// Default colors
$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-teal, 700, 100, 800);
$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-teal, 700, 100, 800);

$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent);
@include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme);

// Dark theme
$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$dark-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$dark-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);

$dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

.dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}

// Light theme
$light-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 200, 500, 300);
$light-accent: mat-palette($mat-brown, 200);
$light-warn: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange, 200);

$light-theme: mat-light-theme($light-primary, $light-accent, $light-warn);

.light-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($light-theme)
}
```

In the app.component file, include OverlayContainer from @angular/cdk/overlay. You can find Angular's documentation for this here https://material.angular.io/guide/theming; though their implementation is a little different. Please note, I also had to include OverlayModule as an import in app.module as well.

In my app.component file, I also declared `@HostBinding('class') componentCssClass;` as a variable, which will be used to set the theme as a class.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OverlayContainer} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public overlayContainer: OverlayContainer) {}

  @HostBinding('class') componentCssClass;

  onSetTheme(theme) {
    this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(theme);
    this.componentCssClass = theme;
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    OverlayModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Finally, call the onSetTheme function from your view.

**app.component.html**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSetTheme('default-theme')">Default</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSetTheme('dark-theme')">Dark</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSetTheme('light-theme')">Light</button>
```

You might consider using an observable so that the functionality would be more dynamic.

Comment: Do you happen to have a suggestion about how to preserve the selected theme on a browser reload?

Comment: @AaronLavers For a simple implementation, I would probably use cookies. A good package I've used is "ngx-cookie-service". You could store the theme name and then search for it OnInit in your component controller.

Comment: @AaronLavers if you would like for the theme to be consistent for the user across all browsers in addition (or instead of) to storing user selected theme in cookies/local storage you can store it server side and when loading the site get the info about user preferences from server

Comment: Worked fine in the Angular 6. Thank you so much!

Comment: This example worked for me except for 1 detail: to switch between a light or dark background, I also had to change the style on the body element, which can be accessed through `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`

Comment: Thanks very much. A minor change (v11.0) - need to remove the original class before adding new as the original appears to hang around causing problems. `this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.remove(this.componentCssClass);`

Answer (score 16):

You have to use the `getContainerElement` method of `OverlayContainer`. Here's some example usage:

```ts
this.overlay.getContainerElement().classList.add('my-theme');
```

As for your style files, I strongly suggest removing this line for both `custom-theme.scss` and `light-custom-theme.scss` (you only need it for your classes in this case):

```scss
@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme); // Remove this line from custom-theme.scss and light-custom-theme.scss
```

If you also want to toggle the theme for your app, you should probably use this in the same `toggleTheme` method:

```ts
toggleTheme(): void {
  if (this.overlay.classList.contains("custom-theme")) {
    this.overlay.classList.remove("custom-theme");
    this.overlay.classList.add("light-custom-theme");
  } else if (this.overlay.classList.contains("light-custom-theme")) {
    this.overlay.getContainerElement().classList.remove("light-custom-theme");
    this.overlay.classList.add("custom-theme");
  } else {
    this.overlay.classList.add("light-custom-theme");
  }
  if (document.body.classList.contains("custom-theme")) {
    document.body.classList.remove("custom-theme");
    document.body.classList.add("light-custom-theme");
  } else if (document.body.classList.contains("light-custom-theme")) {
    document.body.classList.remove("light-custom-theme");
    document.body.classList.add("custom-theme");
  } else {
    this.overlay.classList.add("light-custom-theme");
  }
}
```

- [More info on theming](https://material2-docs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/theming#multiple-themes)
- [Stackblitz demo (For the demo, I had to nest the app in a Sidenav)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-themes-material-so)

Comment: Awesome! this is nearly working as intended, however my body tag isn't updating and is staying in the light theme. It is appearing as `class="mat-app-background custom-theme"` but is still the light theme

Comment: Eh, figured it out, but are we really required to use a side-nav?

Comment: @Surreal You don't really have to place it in a sidenav, just make sure that the `body` has a class of `mat-app-background` in order for the theme to work correctly.

Comment: If you want to use the correct `mat-app-background` you can assign the custom-them-css-class selector to the document's root element within the function `toggleTheme()`:

`document.documentElement.classList.add("custom-theme");`

With adding `class="mat-app-background"`to the `<body>` tag, the correct background color will take effect.

As you call `@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);` within your custom custom-them-css-class mixin, the `mat-app-background` css-selector will become a nested selector.

Answer (score 5):

You cam always check how the theme picker is being implemented in https://material.angular.io/ and just do the same https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/tree/master/src/app/shared/theme-picker by doing so you will have the everlasting solution as in case any breaking changes you always can lookup material docs source how to fix.