# Angular material theme set colors when app start

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 6, and I want to set theme colors when app start.
I need to provide that user define colors in some external json/css file. 
On app run, I will pick up information from json/css and set to material theme. 
Is something similar possible at all ?

Comment: See if helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441036/switch-themes-in-angular-material-5

Comment: Solution from link shows how to change already created themes, I cannot see anything similar to my problem. I need to change properties/colors of the theme when app start.

Comment: yes, Say, you have multiple theme files, and a configuration file. Keep a variable in configuration file, and this variable will tell which theme file to choose from multiple theme files. And in app initializer, read this configuration file variable and pick the theme file. As toggling theme is shown in this link, so insted of toggling we can choose theme according to configuration variable. I dont know this will work or not.

Comment: Milos I think what @Abhishek Kumar is saying is tha the only way to do that is through pre-configured style sheets or 'multiple themes'. Theming is done using SASS (build) not CSS (runtime) so there is no way to dynamically change the palettes and then re-theme the application including the AM components. The only possible way is with pre-configured CSS style sheets.