# Angular material theming

Tags: angular-material

I am new in to the angular material.
I want to change a theme when a user click on one of the two available options:
1] Dark Theme
2] Light Theme

[image]

So when user select Dark Theme / Light Theme then it will change component color(mat-card, mat-toolbar, mat-sidenav-container etc.) as well as font color.

Comment: There are multiple posts on SO regarding this. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47759439/4606040) post and the according stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-material-theming).

Comment: @FabianKung thanks for your response. I checked provided reference but i did't found how to change mat-card bg color and all. So if you know that can you please update the hint or code here, it will really useful to me and other also.

Comment: I have added a `mat-card` from the Angular Material documentation to the stackblitz I linked in the comments [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-material-theming-foxsbc?file=app/app.module.ts). As you can see when you change the theme via the buttons, the background color of the `mat-card` also changes. Maybe it is best if you post your code and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

> For those looking for the solution, check
>   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47759439/4606040) post regarding
>   switching themes on the fly in general and the stackblitz
>   implementation of the same
>   [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-material-theming-foxsbc?file=app/app.module.ts).

Also shows that it works with `mat-card` as asked in this question.