# how to change the angular material theme from indigo-pink to pink-bluegrey by button click

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am new to angular material, I had a requirement change from indigo-pink  to pink-bluegrey by a button click on runtime.

Please help me to do this

Comment: Refer this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441036/switch-themes-in-angular-material-5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch themes in angular material 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441036/switch-themes-in-angular-material-5)